# Using state data as a props in other component conditionally

Tags: reactjs, tags

**Here is my one component DISPLAY,**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ListGroup from "./listGroup";

class Display extends Component {
  handleAllClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    return (
      <ListGroup
        data={this.props.data}
        onSubmitted={this.handleSubmit}
        onClicked={this.handleAllCheck}
        onChanged={this.handleChange}
        onCheckChange={this.handleCheckChange}
        onDeletion={this.handleDelete}
      />
    );
  };

  handleCompleted = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    return (
      <ListGroup
        data={this.props.data}
        onSubmitted={this.handleSubmit}
        onClicked={this.handleAllCheck}
        onChanged={this.handleChange}
        onCheckChange={this.handleCheckChange}
        onDeletion={this.handleDelete}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          type="button"
          className=" all btn btn-light p-1 mr-3"
          onClick={this.handleAllClick}
        >
          All
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className=" act btn btn-light p-1 mr-3"
          onClick={this.handleActiveClick}
        >
          Active
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className=" comp btn btn-light p-1"
          onClick={this.handleCompleted}
        >
          Completed
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Display;
```

Actually I want to use state which is named by `data` in the main component and that `data` contains a boolean variable called `completed`.

Now I wanted to conditionally use this `completed` as props with `ListGroup` component(Which I have imported above).

This should look like this:

```
handleCompleted = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    (!this.props.completedItem &&
      <ListGroup
        data={this.props.data}
        onSubmitted={this.handleSubmit}
        onClicked={this.handleAllCheck}
        onChanged={this.handleChange}
        onCheckChange={this.handleCheckChange}
        onDeletion={this.handleDelete}
      />
    );
  };
```

(I have passed this `completed` as `completedItem` in the main component).
But the problem is this is not working the right way!

Comment: You forgot to return it: `return (!this.props.completedItem &&` ...

Comment: Thanks that solved this problem but i can't get my desire output which is when i click that completed button it will show only those fields which are marked checked. How can I achieve that?